# Is there a way to print/pdf/export bulk data (1000 of records) in ASP.NET MVC using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, printing

I need to print, generate pdf and Excel from bulk data like 1000 of records in an ASP.NET MVC web application.

Is there any efficient way for doing that?

Answer (score 2):

Try using from following options:

1. Rotativa Nuget package
2. SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)
3. iTextSharp

Comment: @jimesh- im using pdfsharp ,thats also good i guess?

Comment: All of these will do your work.
If it's a matter of performance then you will have to see the differences and choose wisely.